# Unexpected template string expression (no-template-curly-in-string) in nuxt.js

Tags: firebase, axios, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I've written some code in nuxt.js where I'm using firebase and axios library to test the output the original code returned a hard-coded .json.  However, in using the following script, nuxt.js throws an error stating that I 'cannot stringify a function to JSON':

```
asyncData (context) {
return axios.get('https://pagebyme-2b11x.firebaseio.com/posts/' + context.params.id + '.json')
  .then((res) => {
    return {
      loadedPost: res.data
    }
  })
  .catch(error => context.error(error))
 }
}

</script>
```

I then tried to modify the code to be the following but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
asyncData (context) {
return axios.get('https://pagebyme-2b11x.firebaseio.com/posts/${context.params.id}')
  .then((res) => {
    return {
      loadedPost: res.data.json
    }
  })
  .catch(error => context.error(error))
 }
}

</script>
```

Would anyone know how to update this at all please?

Comment: do you use axios module?

Comment: yes, the axios module has been imported

Comment: i mean https://axios.nuxtjs.org/ do you use this or the normal axios with `import axios from "axios"`